# Reading data from input form fields and storing them into excel in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, phpexcel, yii2-basic-app

I have used PHPExcel for making a spreadsheet.The spreadsheet is getting populated but with corrupted values.Also the way I have used to get the input field's value is through serialise() which according to my knowledge returns a string.The basic point is how to store these different input field values into this excel file of mine.If there is a problem in my logic then please do tell.
Thanks in advance :)
The controller action-

```
public function actionSaveExcel() {

$test = $_POST;

  print_r($test);


   $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
   $sheet = 0;

   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheet);
   $foos = [
           ['firstname' => $test['list_box_element'],
           'lastname' => 'pat'],

   ];

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);

   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('xxx')
           ->setCellValue('A1', 'Firstname')
           ->setCellValue('B1', 'Lastname');

   $row = 2;

   foreach ($foos as $foo) {

       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . $row, $foo['firstname']);
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B' . $row, $foo['lastname']);
       $row++;
   }

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   $filename = "MyExcelReport_" . date("d-m-Y-His") . ".xls";
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $filename . ' ');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
   $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
   ob_clean();
   $objWriter->save('php://output');

   return $test['list_box_element'];

  // return $objWriter;

}
```

the view-

```
clicked = function () {
   var joo=$('#orderForm formsection[name="ASSET CODE REPORT"]').find('input,select').serialize();
      console.log(joo);

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:  $('#orderForm formsection[name="ASSET CODE REPORT"]').find('input,select').serialize(),
            url: "index.php?r=orders/save-excel",
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: just did @Revolution.

Comment: What does the data in `$test` look like?

Comment: Thanks everybody.Found the solution.So Ajax wasn't required, I directly passed values along with the url and it works.